# Get iFrame contents height using Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

If I had an iFrame I could use this jQuery code to get its contents height but I'm trying to avoid using jQuery in my Angular 2 app. How else would I achieve this?

```
$("#iframe").load(function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("html").height() );
});
```

Comment: Doesn't AngularJS come with jqLite? You could do something like `angular.element("#iframe")` from your directive to get your iFrame.

Comment: That's Angular 1. Angular 2 does not have jqLite.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm dumb, didn't read the title and relied on the tags.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the edit.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: ...no, i did not